# -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to install mod_auth_radius modules .
I downloaded this module and moved it to

```
/var/www/html
```

folder.
after I moved it , I go in this folder and applied this command

```
./configure --add-module=mod_auth_radius.c
```

where mod_auth_radius.c file in this folder
.
but I have this error when I executed it,

```
 -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

when I execute that command with sudo I have this error

```
configure: command not found
```

**Source Code:**
https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/mod_auth_radius

Comment: Please share the source address of sources you used. The most probably you're just in wrong directory, but my crystal ball just broke, so I can't be sure.

Comment: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/mod_auth_radius

Comment: There is no configure so it can't be called. All I found was configure in the Makefile. However that refers to the apache configure, if you want to build it in. I believe you use distro apache package. In that case, use libapache2-mod-auth-radius package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install the `mod_auth_radius` Apache module, it's much easier just to install it through the system's package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-radius
```

Then enable the module in Apache and restart it:

```
sudo a2enmod auth_radius
sudo systemctl restart apache
```